# Golang boolean flag parsing restriction

Tags: go

Can someone elaborate a little more about an explanation from official golang documentation about cmd syntax for boolean flags.

> One or two minus signs may be used; they are equivalent. The last form
>   is not permitted for boolean flags because the **meaning of the command**

```
cmd -x *
```

> **will change if there is a file called 0, false, etc.** You must use the
>   -flag=false form to turn off a boolean flag.

I don't get the point. Could you explain it or give an example?

Comment: what happen if you `ls *`?  if there is a file called `false`,  `cmd -x *` ==> `cmd -x false`, `*` is Wildcard of shell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run `cmd -x *` in a shell, the shell will try to expand the `*` into the list of all files in the current directory. If the current directory contains exactly one file that is named "0" or "false", the shell will execute `cmd -x 0` or `cmd -x false` respectively.

It is unclear whether `cmd -x false` is meant to be understood as `cmd -x=true false` (with "false" being a positional argument), or `cmd -x=false`. So the flag package forces you to make it explicit by requiring the equal sign.